# Testing Renewal of Subscription android

Tags: android, testing, in-app-purchase, subscriptions, auto-renewing

How to test auto renewal of subscriptions in android. I don't want to wait for a month to test it. Is there any way around like in iOS where we can simulate it to renew after 24 hours.

May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?